# Installing ftp without internet access on RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, ftp

I am looking to install ftp (client) on my RHEL server. I can't access the internet directly, so I need to d/l the package.

I have downloaded ftp-0.17-17.2.x86_64 from redhat, and it is telling me:

`libreadline.so.4()(64bit) is needed by ftp-0.17-17.2.x86_64`

when I try and install readline-devel 4, it tells me a newer version is alreadyt installed; and readline 4 tells me it can't install because of conflicts with readline-devel.

`find / -name libreadline* -print
/lib64/libreadline.so.6.0
/lib64/libreadline.so.6
/usr/lib64/libreadline.so`

Can anyone help me to know what the next step is?

Comment: Try to download a more recent version of ftp, for instance `ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64`

Comment: I can't seem to find it on the redhat site. can you give me a link? I'm searching under https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/channels/software/Search.do

Comment: See the answer for a direct link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to download a more recent version of ftp, for instance `ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64.rpm`

See link http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ or http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64.rpm directly.

From the `ldd` output you can see that it is linked to `libreadline.so.6`:

```
ldd /usr/bin/ftp
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa67be000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fe48362c000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fe48340a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe483075000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fe482e54000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe482c50000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe48388b000)
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you :D out of interest, how did you know that a centos package would work for rhel?

Comment: I just typed `google ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64` in the address bar of my browser :-) And since CentOS is a fork of RedHat I know they share the same architecture. For further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS